# How to burn a DVD of Windows 7 with a dump on hard disk

Tags: windows-7, dvd, dvd-burning, bootable-media

Hello I had my Windows 7 DVD with me, and I had earlier copied all the files from it and dumped them into a folder on my computer's hard disk. Now I want to burn a bootable DVD from this dump, how can I do that?

Can somebody help in creating a bootable DVD to troubleshoot a problem on my Windows 7 system. I went on a vacation earlier and lost my original Windows 7 OS DVD, now I only have the dump.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to proceed easily as you will not have a copy of the system files required to make a disk bootable.

What I would personally recommend you do, and what I would do in that situation:

1. Copy all the files you do have to a blank DVD and/or USB stick (I would do USB).
2. Burn a Windows Vista or Windows 7 System Repair disk - Available in `Backup and Restore`

[image]

Then, boot up using the System Repair disk, at the options, choose `Command Prompt`. Navigate to the USB stick or DVD drive and run `<drive>:\sources\setup.exe`.

Setup runs much faster from a USB stick and I think this method is the easiest / best way for you.

Comment: Hello Wil, the problem is, my windows 7 instance is not running at all. It gives me an error which says winload.exe file isn't available and I need to put in my windows installation disc in :(

Comment: It is quite a long way round, but it should still work and be legal - I would recommend getting a trial of Windows 7 - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495 and then performing step 2... The disk may install a trial version of Windows, but it is the fully working Windows PE you care about - It will let you run setup from another disk or USB stick or you may have luck running the recovery tools from it just repairing your installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't copy the boot sector then you will not be able to make a bootable DVD with just the files off the disc.

I would recommend downloading an ISO of your Windows 7 DVD from the internet. [They're available online](http://techpp.com/2009/11/11/download-windows-7-iso-official-direct-download-links/), or you can torrent your version. There's no problem doing this, since you have a license for Windows.

Comment: Sorry taspeotis, appears the both our sites links are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Download a copy of W7 here, use it to do the repair, be sure to select the correct version and bit level

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/04/28/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have another working computer you should be able to use [RTSe7en Lite](http://www.rt7lite.com/) to create a bootable disk from the source you have and repair the install from there. I've not tried this though.

Moab's suggestion is guaranteed to work.